# Any restriction to transfer money from US to Europe (as Iranian person)

Tags: currency

Is there any restriction to transfer some money as a gift to a European account from the US? I need to add:

- I'm an Iranian and a permanent resident in the US (non-citizen).
- The amount is less than $10K.
- Both bank accounts are personal.

Comment: Shouldn't be any restrictions, otherwise the US bank wouldn't let you keep an account in the first place. The bank in Europe will have no clue of your origin/citizenship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Iranian citizen who is an LPR it not discriminated against by the Iran sanctions, so you would have the same right to send gifts to a European recipient as a French LPR in the US would. Sanctions about Iranians are about "persons ordinarily resident in Iran". Which means that sending money to an Iranian uncle who happens to travel to France is restricted (but not because of your status, rather because of his status). You are no longer ordinarily resident in Iran.